# Detecting Right Shift Key in Form KeyUp Event

Tags: events, vb6, keyboard

I want to detect when the right shift key is released on a form in VB6. I have the following code:

```
Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer

Private Sub Form_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If GetKeyState(VK_RSHIFT) < 0 Then
        MsgBox "Right Shift Released"
    End If
End Sub
```

Except, it doesn't work. By the time the event is fired the key has been released and the GetKeyState API function returns 0.

What's the solution?

Comment: What value does that `Shift` parameter contain? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shift parameter tells you what combination of <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys are down. It doesn't distinguish between left and right, though.  For that, you have to use the `GetKeyState` API function.

Trap the right shift key when it goes down with similar code to what you have, but in the `Form_KeyDown` event.  Set a module-level boolean to indicate that the key is now down.  (Note that you'll have to check that `KeyCode` is 16, which you'll get for either shift key.)

Then, in the `Form_KeyUp` event, if your boolean says the key is down, but `GetKeyState` returns a negative number indicating that it's actually up, you know the key has been released.  Make sure you reset the form-level boolean at this time as well.

Comment: That nearly works. Except that in my application, the left and right shift keys do different things. How do I know which has been released? It's possible that both may have been depressed one after the other and released in any order.

Comment: The argument to GetKeyState is the *virtual* key you are interested in, and the right and left shift keys are different virtual keys.  As long as you pass `VK_RSHIFT` (0xA1), you will get the state of that key only.  You'd pass `VK_LSHIFT` (0xA0) to check the left shift key.  I found a list of the keycodes here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx